# Difference between thes expressions: int* a = 0; int* a = 10;

Tags: c, pointers

What is the difference between

```
int* a = 0;
```

and

```
int* a = 10;
```

?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`int* a` declares variable `a` as a pointer to integer.

`=0` and `=10` assign some value to the variable.

Note that `a` is a pointer, its value is supposed to be an address.

- Address `0` has a particular meaning: it's `NULL`, represent an *empty* pointer.
- Address `10` has no meaning: it's a random memory address. Since it's not `NULL`, most functions will consider it a valid address, will dereference it, and thus it will create problems (undefined behavior) to your application.

Comment: int* a and int *a both r same ?

Comment: The mere act of defining `=10` is undefined behavior unless the compiler gives that address a special meaning ("the address of the video memory buffer"). You don't even need to use it.

Comment: @mr_eclair: yes. @peoro: being particularly picky, 10 is not a random address, it is arbitrary. It's always 10, but for no discernible reason.

Comment: @mr_eclair - Yes. Which one is "better" is an ongoing style debate with no good answer. Ignore this holy war and code.

Comment: I would like to add that `int* a = 0;` is a common (good) practice to initialize pointers. You could also do it with `int* a = NULL;`.

Comment: I should mention that 10 may well be a perfectly good address if, for example, you have a memory-mapped device at that address.

Comment: @mr_eclair: They are the same.  Both are parsed as `int (*a)`; the `*` operator is always bound to the declarator.  If you wrote `int* a, b;`, only `a` would be declared as a pointer.

Answer (score 6):

One of these should trigger a warning. Crank up your compiler warnings!

```
int *a = 0;
```

This one is okay. It declares a pointer `a` to an `int` and initializes it to 0, or the `NULL` pointer, which means it points to nothing. Attempting to dereference it will lead to bad things, but you can check whether or not a pointer is valid before you dereference it, so `NULL` pointers are actually good things.

```
int *a = 10;
```

This is not okay. It declares the same pointer to an `int` but initializes it to 10. First, the compiler will complain that the `int` 10 can't be implicitly cast to a pointer type. If you ignore this, the pointer points to memory location 10, which you have *no guarantee* is a valid `int` or a valid anything or even belongs to your process. Dereferencing `a` will be bad, just like dereferencing `a` when it was `NULL`, but what's worse, we have no way to check the validity of `a` because 10 could be good *or* bad - we have no way of knowing until we use it and get what we want/garbage/nasal demons.

Answer (score 4):

```
int* a = 0;
```

Assign 0 to the pointer.

```
int* a = 10;
```

Assigns 10 to the pointer. Note, to the **pointer** (i.e. the variable which should contain an address) not the pointee!

That last one is dangerous, as it *defeats* `NULL` pointer checks.

Answer (score 4):

First, these are not expressions, they're declarations.

```
int* a = 0;
```

This declares a pointer-to-integer and initializes it with a zero compile-time integer constant, which is transformed into a null pointer value. In other words, it declares a null pointer to integer.

```
int* a = 10;
```

This declares a pointer-to-integer that points to whatever your specific compiler defines to be at the address represented by the integer 10. In the vast majority of cases, there's nothing there, so you end up with undefined behavior by merely declaring this pointer.

Answer (score 1):

Here we are asigning value to pointer, int* a = 0; means int a* = NULL; However, in c++, int* a = 10 wont compile, because "Conversion from integral type to pointer type requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast", as compiler thinks 10 is integral type not a pointer.

Comment: This is a good answer, but nowhere did the OP mention C++. +1 if you take out the C++ specific lingo. C is confusing enough to start learning without people trying to tempt you with the dark side. :P